# Circular Reference between Workers + Projects and Employers in SQL Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of Employers and Workers. I need to register the projects an Worker has made for the different Employers but I also need to know the current Worker's Employer. I have:

```
create table dbo.Employers
(
  Id int identity not null 
  Name nvarchar not null
);

create table dbo.Workers
(
  Id int identity not null 
  CurrentEmployerId int not null, -- FK
  Name nvarchar (120) not null, 
);

create table dbo.Projects
(
  Id int identity not null 
  WorkerId int not null, -- FK  
  EmployerToWhichTheProjectWasMadeId int not null, -- FK
  Name nvarchar (120) not null,      
);
```

In dbo.Workers I have an EmployerId FK which states the current Employer.

In dbo.Projects I have two FKs: WorkerId and EmployerId which states that the project was made by Worker X to Employer Y. And since Worker X has a FK Employer that Worker X works currently for Employer Z.

Don't I get a circular reference because of this?

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the model you have, a worker can work in a project that doesn't belong exclusively to its employer. If that's a valid scenario then the model is correct. If that is not possible then you may be able to remove employer id from project as employer will be determined by the worker.

Comment: The reason why my model is that way is: the employer in worker is current employer while employer in project is the employer to which the worked did the job. So it is a past employer. Does this make sense?

Comment: yes, it makes sense; the model is then correct according to the business rules. There is no circular reference, just normal FK dependencies.

Comment: Got it ... That was my doubt. Just marked the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with the above code.  The only requirement is that if you are making a new Worker, you have to have an Employer.  If you are making a new Project you must have both a Worker and an Employer.  A circular reference would be like if Employer needed an EmployerId in order to be created.